# Chronicle Queue - reader modifying msg

Tags: concurrency, chronicle-queue

We are preparing to use Chronicle Queue (SingleChronicleQueue) to record our messages. The prototype is working now. However we have some problems.

Can readers modify the messages? We use a chronicle map to record indices read to remove duplicate messages after a restart. In case this doesn't work, we want to tag messages read on the reader side. Actually we already do that. The problem is now, sometimes, we get error messages like "15c77d8be (62) was 8000003f is now 3f", and we suspect that this is because writes across cache line boundaries are no longer atomic now. What is the recommended way to solve it? Currently we add a one-byte tag before the message, will adding a 3-byte padding solve the problem?

Can we use our own roll policy? We'd like to use an hourly policy. But the hourly policy mandates a file containing less than 256 million entries. Can we use our custom roll cycle? Are there any caveats?

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to record your consumers' read indices in another output queue. On restart, simply read backwards from the end of the output queue to determine what each consumer's read sequence should be.

Without seeing your code it is a little difficult to determine what the problem might be with trying to modify existing records. Note that records inserted into a queue are supposed to be immutable; modifying them from a reader thread is not supported.

With regards to your RollCycle requirements, the LARGE_HOURLY cycle was recently added, allowing ~2 billion entries per cycle:

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/queue/RollCycles.java#L27